# JAVA passing argument

Tags: java

I know that JAVA is passing arguments by value (copy). Why does this code returns John ?

```
public class User {
    String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u = new User();
        u.name = "Sebastian";
        System.out.println(u.name);
        initialize(u);
        System.out.println(u.name);
    }
    public static void initialize(User u){
        u.name = "John";
        System.out.println(u.name);
        User u2 = new User();
        u2.name="dsafsa";
        u = u2;
        System.out.println(u.name);
        u.name = "Lilly";
        System.out.println(u.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your output?

Comment: yes, please, provide more information about output and your problem...

Comment: The big question is *where* it returns John and what you expected instead.

Comment: are you referring to why 'John' is printed in the last line of your main method?

Comment: Because `u` and `u2` are not `User`s, but references to `User`s.

Comment: Yes thats what i am refering to

Comment: Well, you changed the name of `u` from `Sebastian` to `John` on the first line of `initialize`.  So it won't be `Sebastian` any more.  And on the second-to-last line of `initialize`, you changed the name of an entirely different `User` to `Lilly`, so it won't be `Lilly` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference to the object `u` is being passed to the `initialize` method is being passed by value (the value of the reference). This doesn't affect how `u.name` is accessed.

When you execute `u.name = "John"` then you are changing the `u` being passed into  the method (via the reference). This is affecting the same `u` in the `main` method.

[image]

In this image `Person person` is like you `User u` in your `main` method. Inside `initialize` you `User u` is like `Person anotherReferencetoTheSamePersonObject`. So updating one updates the other.

Comment: In this line : User u2 = new User();
  u2.name="dsafsa";
  u = u2; , The user u in main will be "dsafsa" ?

Comment: `u` now point to entirely different user. Think `Person anotherReferencetoTheSamePersonObject` points to another `Person` way off the page. The original `Person person` is still pointing to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is scope problem, when you create a new user in initialize method

```
User u2 = new User();
u2.name="dsafsa";
```

and set it to the argument

```
u = u2;
```

You update only the reference of the argument **in the scope of the method**. But you dont change the user created in main method. Because Java pass arguments by value (the value of the reference).

If you dont change reference of argument

```
public static void initialize(User u) {
    u.name = "John";
    System.out.println(u.name);
    // User u2 = new User();
    // u2.name = "dsafsa";
    // u = u2;
    System.out.println(u.name);
    u.name = "Lilly";
    System.out.println(u.name);
}
```

You realy update the user created in main method. Because the value of the reference is always the one of the user creted in main method.

Answer (score 0):

Because value in your case is a reference pointing to some object. The reference *u* in initialize method is a different one than *u* in main function, but they still point to the same object.

Top rated answer in this post explains it in the detail: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Java always pass arguments by value.

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into
>   methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the
>   passed-in reference still references the same object as before.
>   However, the values of the object's fields can be changed in the
>   method, if they have the proper access level.[[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)]

In this you create a new `User` object and passes it's reference by value to the initialize method. Therefore, inside initialize method you refer to the 
same object you create in you main method. That's the reason why the original object gets modified.

So that  `u.name = "John";` modifies the object you created in main method. After `u = u2;` reference `u` points to the new object created inside `initialize` method. Therefore, `u.name = "Lilly"` modifies the second object.

[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

In main you have `u -(1)-> name`, when `initialize` is called you have `u' -(2)-> u -(1)-> name` and when you do `u = u2` then the reference (2) have changed `u' -(2)-> u2 -(3)-> name2`. So in `u.name = "Lilly";` you are changing u2's name and `u` in main is still unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers above are suffiecient.. adding one more point

Java do not support pass by reference for primitive types, to make it possible Java has something called as Wrapper classes for primitive types through which you can contruct a object for primitive type and pass it by reference.

> What are Wrapper classes?

As the name says, a wrapper class wraps (encloses) around a data type and gives it an object appearance. Wherever, the data type is required as an object, this object can be used. Wrapper classes include methods to unwrap the object and give back the data type. It can be compared with a chocolate. The manufacturer wraps the chocolate with some foil or paper to prevent from pollution. The user takes the chocolate, removes and throws the wrapper and eats it.